# Not Displaying When Creating Custom Cron Job in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm developing a simple Wordpress plugin and what I want is to include crons.

Actually everything seems to be fine but when I check it through plugins like Advanced Cron Manager and WP Crontrol I can't see my function.

I know wordpress crons are not a real cron. They come alive based on site traffic. But shouldn't it still show up in plugins like Advanced Cron Manager and WP Crontrol?

```html
<?php
add_filter('cron_schedules', function($schedules) {
    $schedules['one_minute'] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display'  => __('Every Minute'),
    );
    return $schedules;
});

add_action('wp_loaded', function () {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'one_minute', 'bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook');
    }

    if (!has_action('bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook')) {
        add_action('bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook', 'bha_auto_fetch_publish');
    }
});



function bha_auto_fetch_publish() {
    if (get_option('bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook') == '1') {
        $categories = array('Lorem', 'Lorem', 'Lorem', 'Lorem', 'Lorem', 'Lorem', 'Lorem-Lorem', 'Lorem');
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $posts = pull_from_rss('lorem' . sanitize_title($category) . '/feed', $category, 10);
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                if(!$post['post_published']) {
                    auto_publish_post($post['post_title'], $post['post_content'], $post['post_image'], $post['post_category']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook', 'bha_auto_fetch_publish');

add_action('init', 'schedule_my_cron');
function schedule_my_cron() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'one_minute', 'bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook');
    }
}

function auto_publish_post($post_title, $post_content, $image_url, $post_category) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');

    $media = media_sideload_image($image_url, null);

    if (is_wp_error($media)) {
        return 'Error: ' . $media->get_error_message();
    }

    $attachments = get_posts([
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => null,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ]);

    $first_post = $attachments[0];
    $attachment_id = $first_post->ID;

    $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_content' => $post_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_category' => array(get_cat_ID($post_category))
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

    if ($post_id && $attachment_id) {
        set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment_id);
    }

    return 'Success: ' . $post_id;
}
```

And my simple checkbox

```html
function bha_settings_page() {
    echo '<h1>Ayarlar</h1>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="options.php">';
    settings_fields('bha_settings');
    do_settings_sections('bha_settings');
    echo '<table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Fetch news.</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook" value="1" ' . checked(1, get_option('bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook'), false) . ' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
    submit_button();
    echo '</form>';
}

function bha_register_settings() {
    register_setting('bha_settings', 'bha_auto_fetch_publish_hook');
}
```